# JQuery method .html() doesn't add the full HTML content from JSON response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I have some HTML generated by php using `json_encode()`, which look like this:

```
ob_start();
    if ($my_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'test' );
        endwhile;
                    endif;

$response['content'] = ob_get_clean();

die(json_encode(utf8_encode($response)));
}
```

This is how look the html from the php (wordpress posts):

```
<article id="post-4996" class="post-4996 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-news tag-dog">
  <header class="entry-header">
            TEST
    <a href="http://example.com/test/news/4996" rel="bookmark">Mon post</a> 
    <div>TAGS:<a href="http://example.com/tag/dog" rel="tag">dog</a></div>
   </header>
</article>
```

So with the `json_encode()`. I get the full html output in my JSON reponse, like that.

```
{
 "content":"\n<article id=\"post-4996\" class=\"post-4996 type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-news tag-dog\">\n\t<header class=\"entry-header\">\n\t\t\t\n\t\tTEST\n\t\t\t\t<a href=\"http:\/\/example.com\/test\/news\/4996\" rel=\"bookmark\">Mon post<\/a><div>TAGS:<a href=\"http:\/\/example.com\/tag\/dog\" rel=\"tag\">dog<\/a><\/div>\n\t\t\t<\/header><\/article>\n"
}
```

And this is how i retrieve it in my jquery:

```
var $container    = $('#main');
var $pagePosts    = $container.find('article');
var $myContainer  = $('.my_container');

$pagePosts.wrapAll("<span class='my-container'></span>");

function get_posts($params){

     jQuery.ajax({
           url: mdu.ajax_url,
                data: {
                       action: 'my_get_posts',
                       nonce: mdu.nonce,
                       params: $params
                       },
                       type: 'POST',
                       dataType:'json',
                     success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest {
                             console.log('Success  ', data.content);
                             $pagePosts.empty();
                             $myContainer.html(data.content);
                             }
                    });
                 }
$("a[rel='tag']").click(function(tag){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    clickTag = $(tag.target).text();
                    $params = {'tag' : clickTag,};

   get_posts($params);
 });
```

I add the content using the JQUERY `.html()` method but on it only add the `<article>` tags and not the content (`<header>`,`<a>`,`<div>`,...) which means i have only this as a result in my web page…

```
<article id="post-4996" class="post-4996 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-news tag-dog">
</article>
```

I have check the JSON on jsonlint.com and it's clean, the JSON response correspond to what's expected only the `.html()` seems to be the issue but i don't get why.

EDIT: One thing i have noticed is :

```
 console.log ( $myContainer.outerHTML );
```

return
     undefined

Adding some picture hope this help,

[image: Before the OnClick]

[image: After the OnClick]

Any input much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you show us some code

Comment: Your code works fine in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0tzqgju3/. Please show your code which produces this issue

Comment: there's no php here. If this is php-related and is the root of this problem; post it. Till then, it's anybody's guess. There's also no jQuery/JS here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe 3 DV's and 3 CV's will get his attention!

Comment: @RiggsFolly hard to say if they're in the process of getting an MVCE ready. They'll have to ping one or all. I already left the question but had to obviously come back *lol* ok, I left it (again).

Comment: Sorry about that, php and jQuey/JS code added.

Comment: @MatthieuDucorps I revisited the question and tried to understand what's going on (or not going on here). Although I cannot help you with a solution, can only ask where `$params` is defined and used and to edit your question for it. I also edited your question, adding the ticks `\`` around `<article>` which people did not see (from the start). This highlights special tags. In the meantime, have look at your developer console, do a var_dump and see if there are any errors at all, via php/query etc.

Comment: I have review the question to make it more clear hope this help to find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue, i was declaring my variable to early…

This doesn't work,

```
 var $container    = $('#main');
 var $pagePosts    = $container.find('article');
 var $myContainer  = $('.my_container');

       $pagePosts.wrapAll("<span class='my-container'></span>");
```

But this does work,

```
var $container    = $('#main');
var $pagePosts    = $container.find('article');

       $pagePosts.wrapAll("<span class='my-container'></span>");

var $myContainer  = $('.my_container');
```

kindly

Matth.